# Publish only one parent crate on multi-crate project

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I am creating a library, that is nearly close to its first release, so I would like to upload it to `crates.io`. Library has a multi-crate design, so I ended with something like:

```
- CrateA
- CrateProcMacros
- CrateC
- CrateD
- CrateE
- CrateF
- Cargo.toml (handles the workspace)
- Cargo.lock
...
```

where `CrateA` is the parent of the other crates, and has dependencies on another of those local crates, and some of those crates also depends on another ones. I mean, it's the primary crate of the library, the one responsible for exposing the public API of the project, and the unique one that I would like to be published in `crates.io`.

Reading the [cargo docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) I am seeing that I won't be able to publish a unique crate to the registry. All will be uploaded and published.

So, what alternatives I have to only publish my `CrateA` to the registry? Should I change my project's structure, and move to `CrateA` all the other packages and then try to publish it? Or there's some way to achieve this?

#### EDIT

`CrateA` have direct dependencies on another crates. An those others also depends on another one inside my workspace.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't change the structure of your project. You chose it for some reason. It is more important than packaging. From what I remember you must publish each crate separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Cargo packaging works is that *you are publishing your source code* nearly unchanged. There is no pre-compilation step. There is no step where multiple library crates are gathered into one package. The **only** way to publish your `CrateA` is to publish all of its dependencies too.

There is interest in making a multi-crate project easier to publish, but for now, you've got to do it all explicitly.

1. Make sure each package in your project declares a `[package] name` that makes sense in public. (The name of the directory you keep it in doesn't matter.) It's common to have names like `myproject-partoftheproject`, where the package people actually use normally would be named `myproject`.
2. Make sure that each dependency declaration has a `version` number (not just a `path`) matching what you're going to publish. (You don't have to remove the `path`; that will be done for you within publication.)
3. Publish each package. You must do this in reverse dependency order — that is, `CrateA` last.

No one will mind that you've published extra packages that aren't meant for direct use — for example, lots of libraries necessarily have separate proc-macro packages. Though, if you have any crates that are really *just* for code organization and don't have any particular benefit, you could consider making them into modules inside fewer crates.

Answer (score -2):

master Cargo.toml should be like this

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "CrateA",
    "CrateB",
    ...
]
```

And CrateA/Cargo.toml should be like this

```
[package]
name = "Foo"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"
authors = ["Foo <Foo@gmail.com>"]
license = "Bar"
description = "Baz"
[dependencies]
CrateB = { path = "../CrateB", version = "0.0.0" }
CrateC = "0.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks. Worspace `Cargo.toml` already looks like that, and the rest of `Cargo.toml` files also